# C++ to Python for loop?

Tags: python, c++

I was wondering how I would go about writing the following loop from C++ into python.  So far I have, assume nums is an array with 4 integers:

```
    for i in range(5):
        temp_distance = abs(check-nums[i])
        if ((distance and distance) > temp_distance):
            distance = temp_distance
            close = nums[i]
        else:
            break



   for(std::size_t i = 1; i < table.size(); ++i) 
    {
        int tempDistance = std::abs(temp - table[i]);
        if(distance && distance > tempDistance) //perfect match
        {
            distance = tempDistance;
            closest = table[i];
        }
        else
        {
            break; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look at where your parentheses are in `(distance and distance) > temp_distance`

Comment: it should be: if (distance and (distance > temp_distance))

Comment: You can use len(num) to get the actual size. Or use foreach syntax: "for x in num".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more pythonic way to express your C++ loop, I suggest:

```
for item in nums:
    tempDistance = abs(check - item)
    if distance > tempDistance > 0:
        distance = tempDistance
        closest = item
    else:
        break
```

Expression (distance and distance) as you have it written now des not do much, it basically returns distance, which is probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in nums:
    temp_distance = abs(check-i)
    if (distance and (distance > temp_distance)):
        distance = temp_distance
        close = i
    else:
        break
```